# распознание рукописных цифр с помощью нейросети

Tags: нейронные-сети

Есть желание погрузиться в нейронные сети, в интернете самым распространенным проектом выводит "распознание рукописных цифр", но нигде не удалось найти базу данных этих самых цифр, впрочем как и проекта от начала до конца.
Может кто-то начинал с этого и подскажет как правильно загуглить чтоб найти сам проект от начала до конца и чтоб обязательно имелась база или любезно ссылку скинет.

Comment: возьмите самый (или один из самых) популярных курсов по нейросетям и машинному обучению - https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/home/assignments - там есть урок, посвященный этому, и база символов есть, и готовый проект-домашнее задание.

Comment: Была библиотека NeuronDotNet и там был такой пример (впрочем, с рукопечатными символами) в виде winforms-приложения. Наверное, сейчас будет сложно найти. Код примера был так себе - пришлось много допиливать, чтобы с ним дальше нормально работать, но по сути там всё перечисленное было в работающем виде.